# use textfield to type preset value then print out that value

Tags: java

I made `class a`:

```
class a
int account
string first name
string last name
int balance
```

Then I create a `textfield` in `class b`:

```
class b
textField_4 = new JTextField();
    textField_4.setBounds(210, 123, 150, 30);
    getContentPane().add(textField_4);
    textField_4.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Enter");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                PrintStream diskWriter = new PrintStream("");
                diskWriter.print("Account: ");
                diskWriter.println(account);
```

How do I write the value in `class a account` into the `class b textfield`?

Comment: Where u want to print the value?

Comment: some file on the disk that i'll add later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to get text from textField and print it to text file:

UPDATED : 
**FIRST CLASS :**

```
public class ClassB {

int account = 3000;
String firstname = "Coder";
String lastname = "ACJHP";
int balance = 300;

public String getDatas() {
    return new String(account + firstname + lastname + balance);
  }
}
```

**THIS IS ANOTHER CLASS :**

```
textField = new JTextField();
    ClassB classB = new ClassB(); //INITIALIZING FIRST CLASS
    textField.setText(classB.getDatas());//THERE GETTING THE TEXT AND ADDING TO TEXTFIELD
    textField.setBounds(97, 28, 151, 42);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnPrintIt = new JButton("Print it!");
    btnPrintIt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String text = textField.getText();
            if(!text.equals(null) || text.length() > 0){


                File file = new File("text.txt");                   
                PrintStream printStream;
                try {
                    printStream = new PrintStream(file);
                    printStream.println(text);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }   

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: not what i mean tho. I mean my  "int account"  variable is in one class, and i want to put it in my textField, after then print it to a file. thanks for the help tho

Comment: one more question, can i type instead of put preset value in textfield but still keep the "int" or "string" type?

Comment: public int getDatas(){ accoun = 1000;return account ;
  }

Answer (score 0):

So your "account" variable is in a different class and you want to put it in your textfield?

Well you could declare your account variable as `public int account;`, and in order to call it, you would have to use `class_b variable = new class_b();`, and to put it in your text field, you would use `textField_4.setText(variable.account);`

Hope I helped!

Comment: i thought it's suppose to be class_ variable = new class_a(); ?

Comment: nah not like that